How can quantum mechanics so easily explain atomic transitions?
The interaction of electromagnetic waves with charges is a very complicated process involving a detailed analysis of relativity and Maxwell's equations that show us how acceleration of charges emit radiation in the form of photons. However, with simple quantum mechanics and perturbation theory we can easily show that these transition occur, yet the only bit of EM we included in the Hamiltonian is the $E\cdot\hat{d}$ term. How is this so easily done?

There are different levels of approximation, and one does not necessarily need to use the most complete known theory to explain a phenomenon at hand. Let me mention just a few:
Fermi Golden rule
This is sufficient to explain transitions when matter interacts with strong driving EM field.

That field is strong means that the number of photons is very high, and we can neglect its fluctuations - to the extent that we ignore creation and annihilation of photons - indeed, what interests us is the changes in the matter (transitions between energy levels).
The times are short - this allows to neglect the saturation effects leading to Rabi oscillations.
Fast decoherence due to unspecified interactions - so that we can assume that the wave function collapses once transition has occurred.
The matter is non-relativistic.

Einstein coefficients
These are in a way a simplification even in comparison to the FGR, but they do take into account something that FGR cannot do: the spontaneous emission. But the coefficients are phenomenological - good enough for writing the rate equations and constructing a laser. However, if we want to calculate these coefficients from the first principles, we do need to work harder - considering interaction (of still non-relativistic matter) with quantized EM field. Surely quantized Em field is relativistic, but its relativistic nature is "trivial" - it is already encoded in the Maxwell equations, and was well known before the theory of relativity emerged (in fact, it is one of the reasons, why the theory of relativity emerged.)
Jaynes-Cummings model
Considering just one EM mode - no Lamb shift or spontaneous emission would emerge in this approach, but some other effects can be captured.
Rabi oscillations
Can be obtained by solving self-consistently equations for a two-level system - just one step beyond the Fermi Golden Rule... but the field can still be treated as classical.
And so on, and so forth.
The fact is that physicists use a lot of models - descriptions the simplest description sufficient to capture (and hence explain!) the phenomenon of interest. The most complicated and complete theory is not necessarily the best one - the point famously illustrated by Borges in On Exactitude in Science.

Thanks for the long answer. I suppose I was just surprised at how our simple models are so successful at explaining complex interactions, but that seems to be a recurring theme in physics.

@Eli One of the reasons that all these approximations are possible is the small fine structure constant (as pointed out by JEB), which enables perturbative treatment of electromagnetic interactions. This is apparently not the case with strong and weak forces, but I am not qualified to discuss it.

$$\alpha \approx \frac 1 {137} \ll 1 $$
That's how. So when you do a standard quantum mechanics calculation, the leading order term (the dipole) is sufficient.

+1 This is no doubt a good point, but deserves to be expanded.
